# Can I add Pseudo Element "after element" instead of "after content of element"?

Tags: css, dom, css-float, pseudo-element

I usually use `::after` to add a pseudo-element, which add **after the content** of the element:

```
.clear-after:after
{
    content: '.';
    display:block;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}
```

Is there a way to add the pseudo element **after the element** where I apply the class instead of **after the content of the element** where I apply the class?

Because if I have a list of 10 items and a grid of 3 column, I could avoid to add a `clear` DOM/HTML element (div) every 3 items (usually done server-side) and just do the job with CSS.

Comment: This sounds like a job for ::nth-child(n) to me

Comment: ::nth-child(n) it's a selector. It won't `add` pseudo element "after/next/later".

Comment: Yes, I know. But for you specific "clear every third element" it is perfect: https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Comment: I don't get it! Can you give to me an example?

Comment: @markzzz I guess you can clear floats for the grid either using the 'clear div' or wrapping each row with an element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add an ::after element after the element itself, but for your specific "clear every third item" case, ::nth-child can help:

```css
html {
  font-family: helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>List element 1</li>
  <li>List element 2<br />Some more</li>
  <li>List element 3</li>
  <li>List element 4</li>
  <li>List element 5</li>
  <li>List element 6</li>
  <li>List element 7</li>
  <li>List element 8</li>
  <li>List element 9</li>
</ul>
```